# Mapping video/mp4 to download instead of play

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am using Firefox on Ubuntu 10.4.  I want to download [a TED movie](http://download.ted.com/talks/JessaGamble_2010G.mp4) but my browser forces me to play it.  The player it shows has no apparent option to save the video.  I can save the video if I do a wget on the URL, but that seems like a harder route than normal.

I found a promising dialog in Edit|Preferences|Applications.  I set "MPEG4 Video" to "Always ask" and every other video format I could find also to "Always Ask".  I think I'm missing the mapping from video/mp4 to "Always Ask".  It's probably missing from the dialog in some sort of assumption that everyone would always want to play a video/mp4 directly in firefox.

In short, is there a way to map video/mp4 to "Always Ask"?

BTW:  My ISP's "unlimited plan" limits me to only 5GB per month, so I want to download my favorite videos and watch them locally as many times as I want.  Fellow Americans, beware of "unlimited" plans.

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing to *about:plugins* and disabling any media player plugins that appear there, such as Totem or VLC.